# Replace JSON key value without quotes

Tags: rest, karate

My temp variable at run-time's value is: ["1363097.0"]
I want to replace this below mentioned text  with this temp variable.
But when I try replace command, it takes it as a String and makes the value as "["1363097.0"]"

Now, because of the API spec, this value should be ["1363097.0"] and API is not accepting the string.

I have tried Embedded expression logic of #(temp) as well but it also does the same and makes it as a String with double quotes around it.

So, how do I make it take the value straightaway and not understand it as a String and not append quotes.

```
* def data =
    """

{
  "searchParameters": {
    "filters": [
      {
        "name": "Organisation",
        "operator": "=",
        "value": <foo>
      }
    ]
  }

}
    """
    * replace data.foo = temp
```

Already tried using set keyword for updating the value in JSON but it also makes it as a String and automatically appends quotes around it.

Answer (score 2):

use `set` instead of `replace`,

```
* def temp = ["1363097.0"]
* set data.searchParameters.filters[0].value = temp
```

refer - [karate set documentation](https://github.com/intuit/karate#set)

Comment: I already tried using set. When I post the request after doing set, i can see it again makes it as a string when posting. I need to override it somehow.

Comment: Can you please update your question with exact snippet you tried

Comment: Resolved it by: Convert json to string. Use JAVA helper to replace the variable. Then change the updated string back to json. And then post it.

Comment: Good.. if you wish you can post your answer here, it will be helpful and you can accept it as well